# How to reduce memory usages on larg objects logging in winston daily file rotate transport?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, memory-leaks, amazon-ec2, winston

I have configured winston to log in two different files with a custom log.js file to rotate logs on hourly basis across different module.

## Log.js

```
var winston = require('winston');
// setup winston for request log
winston.loggers.add('request', {
    transports: [
      // Setup your shared transports here for request log

      new (winston.transports.DailyRotateFile)({ 
        name: '/var/log/nodejs/request.log',
        level:'info',
        filename : '/var/log/nodejs/request.log' ,
        datePattern: '.yyyy-MM-dd-HH'
      }),
    ]
  });

// setup winston for response log
winston.loggers.add('response', {
    transports: [
      // Setup your shared transports here for bids log

      new (winston.transports.DailyRotateFile)({ 
        name:'/var/log/nodejs/response.log',
        level:'info',
        filename :  '/var/log/nodejs/response.log' ,
       datePattern: '.yyyy-MM-dd-HH'})
    ]
  });

winston.remove(winston.transports.Console);
// to provide the each category across the module ;
 module.exports.requestlog = winston.loggers.get('request');
 module.exports.responselog = winston.loggers.get('response');
```

I am using this log file to store logs from various file using this.Sample in our server.js

## Server.js

```
var requestlog = require('./log.js').requestlog;

var requestObject = {}// large json object with more that 60 key and value  
request.info('request',requestObject);
```

After one hour the memory usages from the top shows more than 3gb ram is consumed in EC2.(Most of the part is showed as cached)which increase the latency of entire application.

If i remove the winston , my application works fine and total memory is always around 1.4 to 1.5 gb.

Is there any way to over come this situation.

My log files is around 2Gb for each hour and i am using gzip to compress the file and then send it to s3 using aws cli.